# Good Infinite Scroll library in Reactjs with focus on performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a calendar for a lot of days.

The user has to scroll the calendar to see the content. So the performance of the application is not good.

Is there any technique or library in reactjs to scroll like this:

> http://yaireo.github.io/infinite

It deletes the olds note

Comment: What do you mean by `it deletes the olds notes`? Do you need all the rows of the calendar loaded into the DOM at everytime ?

Comment: I need only a handful of items are being rendered to the screen at any given time

Comment: In that case, I think both libraries commented above should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
npm i react-virtualized
```

npm package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized

Infinite loader example:

https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/InfiniteLoader

Comment: demo link: https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

Answer (score 0):

Install [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller) using:

```
yarn add react-infinite-scroller
```

or

```
npm i react-infinite-scroller
```